# Axios Pre-flight request is getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin however error says the header is not present

Tags: vue.js, iis, cors, axis

Headers received through preflight options call:

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Allow: POST,OPTIONS
```

Still the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.29.7/rest/api/login' from
> origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Backend: IIS,

Frontend: Vue (Axios):

```js
return axios
.post('//192.168.29.7/rest/api/expenseAPI/login',credentials, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
  .then(({ data }) => {
     ...
  })
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to install the cors module in iis and set the below code in web.config file:

```
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. However, as I mentioned in the question, all the headers are returned properly from the server. However, Axios is still throwing preflight error.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, CORS is not a frontEnd issue if you're using nodejs in the backEnd try to use CROS middleware if you're using Laravel you can make a middleware that returns

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

*PS defaults header is axios is Content-Type: application/json you don't have to write that*

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here the problem is that server is indeed returning the header and it is visible on the developer tools (network tab). However the browser somehow is not recognizing it.